# Lagrangian for a fixed number of non-interacting, non-relativistic bosons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, chemical-potential, superfluidity

In my book on QFT, (during an explanation of superfluidity) the author states that the lagrangian for a fixed number of non-interacting, non-relativistic bosons is $$i\Phi^{\dagger}\partial _{0}\Phi-\frac{1}{2m}\nabla\Phi^{\dagger}\cdot \nabla\Phi + \mu\Phi^{\dagger}\Phi$$ where $\mu$ is the chemical potential.
However, I do not understand this - why is there a need for a chemical potential term if the number of bosons remains fixed? Any explanations of the need for this term would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since $N$ is constant $\mu \int \psi^\dagger \phi= \mu N$ is fixed, so  it just sets the zero of energy to be be that of the ground state of the $N$-body system.   Note that $\mu$ is usually negative for bosons.